# Shutting down twisted server

Tags: python, tcp, server, twisted

I have a twisted [ServerFactory](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/17.5.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory.html) that I am using to push jobs off to clients. The protocol contains a queue that holds all of the jobs. Once this queue is exhausted if a client requests a new job, the server will disconnect the client. Eventually this will leave no clients connected and the server will be ready to shut down.

My question is this:

### Is there a generally accepted best practice for shutting down a ServerFactory once it has completed its work?

I know that for clients the best practice is to use [twisted.internet.task.react](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.html#react) to connect and handle the loss of connection, thus closing the parent process. But I'm not sure if that is the case for a server as well.

Currently this is how I handle shutting down:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver


class ServerProtocol(LineReceiver):
    """Twisted Protocol for sending and receiving lines of bytes."""
    clients = []
    logger = logging.getLogger('launcher.Launcher.RunServer')

    def connectionMade(self) -> None:
        """When a connection is made add the client to the clients list."""
        self.clients.append(self)

    def lineReceived(self, line: bytes) -> None:
        """Whenver a line is received send work to the sending client.

        Parameters
        ----------
        line
            The message received from a client.

        """
        msg = 'Received: ' + line.decode('utf-8') + ' from ' +\
            self.transport.hostname
        self.logger.info(msg)
        if not self.queue.empty():
            run = self.queue.get()
            run_bytes = bytes(run, 'utf-8')
            self.logger.info('Sending run bytes to %s',
                             self.transport.hostname)
            self.sendLine(run_bytes)
        else:
            self.clients.remove(self)
            self.transport.loseConnection()
            if not self.clients:
                self.logger.info('Shutting down RunServer')
                self.reactor.stop()


class RunServer(object):
    """Class for containing twisted server components.

    Parameters
    ----------
    workers
        List of workers that will serve as clients.
    queue
        Queue of runs to execute.

    Attributes
    ----------
    factory
        Twisted ServerFactory for producing protocols.

    """
    def __init__(self, queue: Queue) -> None:
        self.factory = ServerFactory()
        self.factory.protocol = ServerProtocol
        self.factory.protocol.queue = queue
        self.factory.protocol.reactor = reactor

    def start(self) -> None:
        """Start the server and thereby the execution of runs."""
        self.factory.protocol.reactor.listenTCP(80, self.factory)
        self.factory.protocol.reactor.run()
```

As you can see I am storing the reactor in `self.factory.protocol.reactor` and using `reactor.stop` once all of the jobs have been exhausted and clients have disconnected.

I'm pretty sure I have read before that this is not the accepted pattern for running clients and I assume the same goes for servers, but I have yet to see a good example.

Comment: There's nothing explicitly "wrong" with this design

Comment: @notorious.no I agree, but according to the docs `react` "is intended as the way to start up an application with a well-defined completion condition."  Check out the answer for a version following that spirit.

Comment: In this new age of AWS & Docker severs that stop will be more common. Most current twisted servers run continuously. I was trying to reaffirm to you that your script is valid. Great answer btw

Answer (score 1):

I have to credit an acquaintance with this one.

There is absolutely no need for the RunServer class. Subclassing `ServerFactory` and placing the logic from `RunServer.__init__` into the subclasses `__init__` will allow the same behavior with better control. Then you can just define a `main` method and use `react` as it is described in the documentation ([`twisted.internet.task.react`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.html#react))

Here is the updated code:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver


class QueueingProtocol(LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self) -> None:
        self.factory.connectionMade()

    def connectionLost(self, reason) -> None:
        self.factory.connectionLost(reason)

    def lineReceived(self, line: bytes) -> None:
        msg = 'Received: ' + line.decode('utf-8') + ' from ' +\
            self.transport.hostname
        self.logger.info(msg)
        if self.factory.empty():
            self.transport.lostConnection()
        else:
            run = self.factory.get()
            run_bytes = bytes(run, 'utf-8')
            self.logger.info('Sending run bytes to %s',
                             self.transport.hostname)
            self.sendLine(run_bytes)


class QueueingFactory(ServerFactory):
    protocol = QueueingProtocol

    def __init__(self, queue) -> None:
        self.queue = queue
        self.connections = 0
        self.queueHandled = Deferred()

    def connectionMade(self) -> None:
        self.connections += 1

    def empty(self):
        return self.queue.empty()

    def get(self):
        return self.queue.get()

    def connectionLost(self, reason) -> None:
        self.connections -= 1
        if self.connections == 0 and self.empty():
            self.queueHandled.callback("done")


def main(reactor, queue):
    factory = QueueingFactory(queue)
    reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
    return factory.queueHandled
```

Then you can just import `main` where you need it and call `react(main, [some_queue])`